# How do I resolve the pod install error on flutter?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.4
  google_maps: ^4.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  rxdart: ^0.24.1
```

> Pod install
> Analyzing dependencies cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK
> version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core' firebase_auth: Using
> Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core' firebase_core:
> Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core' [!]
> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "cloud_firestore":   In Podfile:
> cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)
>
> Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from` .symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but
> they required a higher minimum deployment target.
>
> [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on
> target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a
> platform for this target in your Podfile. See
> `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

**I get this error on terminal whenever I try to install pod.**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As the error said, we have incompatibility with the firebase package so:
I went to the Podfile and upgrade to 10 (platform :ios, '10.0') and the error go away;

as additional note:
I had that line commented before, so my first try was uncomment and upgrade to 9, but it wasn't work.

Comment: Thats okey. but i face another problem


>  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0

error: Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.

Answer (score 28):

This problem mainly occur when using a MacBook with the M1 chip.

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging":
```

In Podfile:
firebase_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`) was resolved to 10.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/Messaging (= 8.0.0)

The Solution here is to try the following steps:

## Cocoa Pods Installation in M1

- sudo gem install cocoapods
- sudo gem install ffi
- arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
- sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin

## Install ffi

- sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

#update repo

- arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

## Flutter iOS builds

- flutter clean
- flutter build ios

## Re-install dependency in iOS folder of flutter project

- arch -x86_64 pod install

Comment: This can be useful to fix the "pod install" error for sqlite flutter plugin

Comment: or try this  `solution` (https://armen-mkrtchian.medium.com/run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-and-macos-big-sur-developer-transition-kit-b62acffc1387)

Comment: Worked for my Macbook Air M1

Comment: Thanks for the solution...works like a charm and it was really a needed solution...
Adding to this solution I would say you must uncomment the line "platform :ios, '9.0'" in the Podfile and change the version from 9 to 11.4 or above, this is an important step

Comment: this really saved my time.

Answer (score 14):

upgrade to 10 (platform :ios, '10.0') its work but face another issue

> cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.

## Solution

It can be solved by executing the following commands in the terminal.

1. Go to /ios folder inside your Project.
2. Delete Podfile.lock
3. Run pod install --repo-update (Make sure your cd into the iOS directory of the flutter app)
4. Run flutter clean
5. Once complete, rebuild your Flutter application: flutter run

Answer (score 7):

`arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update` works, i just tried it before but then i realised that you have to delete the **Podfile.lock** file located in your ios folder app/ios.

I've also updated the platform to "platform :ios, '12.0'" & this is what it's working on.

[image]

This answer works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636592/12592516.

Then you just have remove `Podfile.lock`

And this is on M1 chip.

I've struggled a lot with this but now I understand, I hope that this helps!

Comment: try this: `flutter clean && flutter pub get && arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update` to clean your project and then get the podfiles updated

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the answer! It took quite some time to figure this out. For those looking and using Visual Studio Code. After you run the debugger, and Podfile will be created for you. At the top of the Podfile file in the ios/ directory, uncomment the line to read:
platform :ios, '10.0'

Answer (score 1):

Go To your iOS folder, run pod repo remove trunk
then pod update.. and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I encounterwd this problem with my mac m1 pro.
Removed the Podfile from my project.
I was using terminal inside the VSCode kept getting errors.

`` [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory. ``

Opened terminal on my macbook and ran:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '9.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing Firebase (9.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop (9.4.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (9.3.0)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop (9.4.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (9.3.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (9.4.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (9.4.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (9.4.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (9.3.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (9.4.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (9.3.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage (9.3.0)
Installing FirebaseStorageInternal (9.3.0)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (2.0.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.2.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.7.0)
Installing Libuv-gRPC (0.0.10)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.1.1)
Installing abseil (1.20211102.0)
Installing cloud_firestore (3.4.3)
Installing firebase_auth (3.6.2)
Installing firebase_core (1.20.0)
Installing firebase_messaging (11.4.4)
Installing firebase_storage (10.3.4)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.44.0)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.44.0)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30909.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 6 dependencies from the Podfile and 30 total pods installed.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lriWX.png)

After that finished I ran the same command:  arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update inside VSCode and said: Pod installation complete! There are 6 dependencies from the Podfile and 30 total pods installed.

They key was removing Podfile from my project. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference these link:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/594
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9152

I changed this in file pubspec.yaml and resolve my problem

```
google_mobile_ads:
git:
  url: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter
  ref: 356875362ddb2ac2e0056385d2729c093722fb8d
  path: packages/google_mobile_ads
```

My final file look like this

```
#  google_mobile_ads: ^1.3.0
  google_mobile_ads:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter
      ref: 356875362ddb2ac2e0056385d2729c093722fb8d
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads
#  firebase_core:  ^1.20.0
  firebase_core:  ^1.18.0
#  firebase_analytics: ^9.3.0
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.10
```