# Error Pod install with firebase plug in | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have flutter app when i try run in mac i get error Pod Install
and i try install pod by run this command in ios folder

> pod install

i get this issue

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '8.5.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
```

stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.11.0.beta.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.2.25
        Host : macOS 11.5.1 (20G80)
       Xcode : 12.5.1 (12E507)
         Git : git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

Plugins

```
cocoapods-clean       : 0.0.1
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

Pod file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

#### Error

```
JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/round_rob'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:748:in `from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:722:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:188:in `specification'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:58:in `block in specification_name'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/set.rb:56:in `specification_name'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:216:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `block in search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `select'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/aggregate.rb:83:in `search'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:416:in `create_set_from_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:385:in `find_cached_set'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:360:in `specifications_for_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:165:in `search_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:274:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_by!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:267:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:60:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:77:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:59:in `sort_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:754:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:744:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:727:in `activate_new_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0.beta.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'


――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
```

but when i delete **Firebase plug-in**

```
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.4.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.4
  admob_flutter: ^1.0.1
```

pod install fine :(

how can i solve this issue ?

i try everything in web but its didn't work :(

flutter doctor its all good :)

Answer (score 0):

**found here:** [How do I resolve the pod install error on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943260/how-do-i-resolve-the-pod-install-error-on-flutter)

**Cocoa Pods Installation in M1**

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

**Install ffi**

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

**#update repo**

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

**Flutter iOS builds**

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```

**Re-install dependency in iOS folder of flutter project**

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times error occur with android terminal.
Use normal terminal

**pod clean**

**pod install**