# Flutter pod install error with 'cloud_firestore'

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

I have a Mac with M1 chip. When I'm trying to debug a flutter project with 'cloud_firestore' package I'm getting this error bellow:

```
Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `geolocator_apple` from `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator_apple/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_maps_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_maps_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `location` from `.symlinks/plugins/location/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `maps_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/maps_launcher/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore":
      In Podfile:
        cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)
    Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

I have tried:

1- Go to Podfile and changed "platform :ios, '8.0'" to 9.0 and 10.0

2- flutter clean > flutter pub get

3- I deleted pod and run pod install

4- Also run this commands:

> arch -x86_64 pod update
>
> arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update

But still getting same error. Any help how to fix this?

Comment: Based on the error message: `Automatically assigning platform iOS with version 9.0`, it doesn't look like the Podfile is setting the version despite #1

Comment: I'm not familiar with your issue but I found a similar question with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636592/12512650), in the comments of that answer they shared [this guide](https://armen-mkrtchian.medium.com/run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-and-macos-big-sur-developer-transition-kit-b62acffc1387) some users commented that this fixed their issue. Please let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.

Problem was in 'main.dart'. I changed 'main' function from this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

to this:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

So, I think options parameter on `Firebase.initializeApp()` is **required** now.
Adding options with FlutterFire CLI solved my problem.
Also, here documentation for this:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli

Comment: How did you get access to DefaultFirebaseOptions?

Comment: It's from firebase_options.dart file. It is mentioned in the document I shared.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that worked for me. I think the problem stems from the default cocoapods install, as instructed on the cocoapods front page, has some M1 incompatibilities with its FFI (foreign function interface).

Installing cocoapods via homebrew instead, ensures that you are getting an apple silicon compatible version.

[These instructions](https://dev.to/staceypyee/installing-cocoapods-on-m1-macbook-air-big-sur-h0l) worked for me.

But it boils down to [uninstalling cocoapods](https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine) and reinstalling it via homebrew:

brew install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

1-   `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`

2-    `arch -x86_64 pod install`

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of firebase requires some updating and this is what worked for me

updated firebase on pubspec to [latest version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios) then ran the following

`firebase login`

`dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`

`flutterfire configure`

deleted outdated Podfile.lock file

`rm ios/Podfile.lock`

updated the Podfile

`pod repo update`

build the project

`flutter build ios`

Answer (score 0):

try this combination:

1. remove .symlinks && /Pods && podfile.lock
2. pod deintegrate
3. pod repo update
4. pod install

Try run it!