# Flutter: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase"

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-build, flutter-ios-build

I have been working on update for a Flutter app that uses `Firebase Firestore`, once I finished the updated and starting to build it for IOS, I got the following error message which cause the build operation to fail:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":
    In snapshot (Podfile.lock): 
       Firebase/Auth (= 9.3.0)

    In Podfile:
       firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 3.3.12, which depends on Firebase/Auth (= 8.14.0)
```

**Note:** The error message in the question says `Firebase/Auth` package but it also happened with other `Firebase` packages.

So what should I do to get over this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are using `Firebase Firestore` in your app, then your case might be the same of mine.

In the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) of `Firebase Firestore` for Flutter, you will notice an **Optional** step that tells you to add a line in the `Podfile` to improve iOS & macOS build times by including the pre-compiled framework, like this one:

```
target 'Runner' do
  ...
  # This is the mentioned line
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.15.0'
  ...
end
```

The solution for me was to update the `tag` number in the link in the line with the latest one from the [repository](https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks) on GitHub. Which repo? the one in the line.

At the dropdown that lets you select the `branch` you will find a tab for selecting a `tag`, just tap it and check the latest version number and use it in the line, e.g. The latest version for the time of this answer is `9.3.0`, so the line would be:

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '9.3.0'
```

If it did not work, then you may totally ignore this optional step and remove this line from the `Podfile`. The build operation would take longer than before but it is better than a build failure.

Comment: Yes! This solved it for me after trying all the other suggestions out there. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was running `pod repo update` from the XCode app directory ("ios/app" for capacitor apps) and then the `pod install` command.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue with Sentry. When building for *MacOS*, I kept getting the error

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Sentry/HybridSDK":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Sentry/HybridSDK (= 7.31.5)

  In Podfile:
    sentry_flutter (from `Flutter/ephemeral/.symlinks/plugins/sentry_flutter/macos`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on Sentry/HybridSDK (= 8.4.0)
```

I had tried deleting `ios/Podfile.lock` and the `ios/Pods` directory, reinstalling `gem`, `ffi`, `cocoapods`, running `pod` using Rosetta etc. But it turned out that all the StackOverflow posts, articles and Github issues were about *iOS, not MacOS*.

The fix was simply to delete `macos/Podfile.lock` and run `flutter build macos`.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same error but the correct answer didnt work for me so i deleted the Pod.lock file and applied this steps.
so this The Solution worked for me:

Cocoa Pods Installation in M1

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Install ffi

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

#update repo

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Flutter iOS builds

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```

my answer is based on [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636592/6561930)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using such a  line in your podfile

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.3.0'
```

then you need to check the repo's latest version from here to keep your pub.dev firebase packages compatible :

[pre-compiled framework version](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core/ios/firebase_sdk_version.rb)